# JavaScript - Unable to access a function

Tags: javascript, function

Need help in accessing saluteFriends and sayHelloLater methods from the code below. I am getting confused between the method scope. Guessing because either of the methods are private and hence not accessible.

```
    function Person(name, friends) {
        // friends is a list of strings 
        var say = function (sentence) {
            console.log(name + ' says: ' + sentence);
        };

        Person.prototype.sayHello = function (otherName) {
            this.say('hello ' + otherName + '!');

        };

        this.saluteFriends = function () {
            friends.forEach(function (friend) {
                sayHello(friend);
            });
        };

        this.sayHelloLater = function (delay, otherName) {
            setTimeout(function () {
                this.sayHello(otherName);
            }, delay);
        };
    }

    var frnds = ["sam", "mathew"];
    var fcall = new Person("alan", frnds);
    fcall.saluteFriends();
```

Comment: The `sayHello` function is the value of a property on the prototype. You can't call it by referring to it as just "sayHello".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are differences, functions on the prototype are **created once** and shared between each instance, instead of functions created in the constructor, which are **created as new objects** for **each** new object created with the constructor.

So, you can't call a prototype function with the `this` keyword. Moreover, you have declared the `say()` function as a private member of your object, so you don't need of the `this` keyword.

```
function Person(name, friends) {
    // friends is a list of strings 
    var say = function (sentence) {
        console.log(name + ' says: ' + sentence);
    };

    Person.prototype.sayHello = function (otherName) {
        //say function is a private function, no need of "this" keyword
        say('hello ' + otherName + '!');

    };

    this.saluteFriends = function () {
        friends.forEach(function (friend) {
            //sayHello function is attached to the prototype, bind the context
            this.sayHello(friend);
        }.bind(this));
    };

    this.sayHelloLater = function (delay, otherName) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.sayHello(otherName);
        }.bind(this), delay);
    };
}

var frnds = ["sam", "mathew"];
var fcall = new Person("alan", frnds);
fcall.saluteFriends();
fcall.sayHelloLater(1000, "john");
```

For your information, i have made the same code in ES2015, which allow us to use `class`, `arrow function` or `string interpolation`. Moreover, arrow function does not bind its own `this`.

```
class Person {

  constructor(name, friends) {
    this.name = name;
    this.friends = friends;
  }

  say(sentence) {
    console.log(`${this.name} says: ${sentence}`);
  }

  sayHello(otherName) {
    this.say(`hello ${otherName}`);
  }

  saluteFriends() {
    this.friends.forEach(friend => this.sayHello(friend));
  }

  sayHelloLater(delay, otherName) {
    setTimeout(() => this.sayHello(otherName), delay);
  }

}

const person = new Person("paul", frnds);
person.saluteFriends();
person.sayHelloLater(1000, "jack");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function Person(name, friends) {
    // friends is a list of strings 
    this.say = function (sentence) {
        console.log(name + ' says: ' + sentence);
    };

    Person.prototype.sayHello = function (otherName) {
        this.say('hello ' + otherName + '!');

    };

    this.saluteFriends = function () {
        friends.forEach(function (friend) {
            this.sayHello(friend);
        }.bind(this));
    };

    this.sayHelloLater = function (delay, otherName) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            this.sayHello(otherName);
        }, delay);
    };
}

var frnds = ["sam", "mathew"];
var fcall = new Person("alan", frnds);
fcall.saluteFriends();
```

You need to attach the function `say` as a method on the object being created.  So change `var say` to `this.say`.  You then need to `.bind` the `this` context to the `forEach` method inside of `saluteFriends`.  Otherwise `this` inside of `forEach` refers to the callback function.  You then need to invoke `sayHello` by placing `this` in front of it, like this: `this.sayHello`.